# TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling

Hello I am a beginner at programming. I am reading Zed Shaw's book Learn Python the Hard Way and I encountered an error I found strange. I am wondering why it keeps giving me the error: TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len() after I run my code in Windows Powershell. The code I ran:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file, "r")

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(in_file)
```

It says the error is in the last line. I do not understand why this error occurs because if I'm right I opened my file in read mode and saved it in the variable in_file. So why wouldn't it be able to read the len of in_file? In Zed Shaw's book he wrote

```
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()
```

in the place where I had written

```
in_file = open(from_file, "r")
```

with the comment: `# we could do these two on one line, how?`So I assumed he wanted me to write the code I had written.

Would appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: "So I assumed he wanted me to write the code I had written." - nope. You seem to have misunderstood what that `"r"` means.

Comment: Opening the file in read mode is substantially different from _reading the file_. It's the difference between opening a book with the intent to read it (as opposed to highlight or underline passages) and actually reading it.

Comment: FYI: http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he want you to do like this `in_file = open(from_file).read()`
in_file is reference to your opened file.
If you want to store content of your file and not reference of it, you can do as above.

```
file = open("/path/to/file.txt").read()
```

after this `file` will give you content of file and you can use `file` variable to get length of content like this
`len(file)`, after you will get number of symbols in content of your file

I hope it was make sense for you.

**NOTE**

this is bad practice, you need to keep your files reference and do your actions with reference.

Comment: "he want you to do like this `in_file = open(from_file).read()`" - but **don't** do it that way, because you're discarding the reference to the file and relying on the reference counting mechanism to close it for you. This is especially dangerous for writes, where your writes could get delayed or even lost if your code ever runs on a non-refcounted Python implementation.

Comment: I agree, but for task it is ok

Comment: Please adopt the habit of posting *actual text* into your answer, and using the `{}` button or Ctrl-K to format it as code. Pictures are not accessible, copyable or particularly reusable.